# Could a lipo/18650 overheat during discharge?

Tags: batteries, safety, lithium-ion, lipo

Suppose a cheapish lipo/18650 has a typical protection circuit in place, which, e.g., shuts off the battery when voltage gets too low, shuts off the battery when the current exceeds 4A, and prevents over-charging.

If the battery becomes old and begins to fade, and the charging device draws more current than the battery offers, could excessive heat be generated *without* causing an under voltage, and thus, getting through the protection circuit? Generating heat without the voltage dropping too low could be an unpreventable hazard, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your cell will heat by dissipating I^2R power through its' internal resistance. Since the resistance is inside the cell and your protection circuit is measuring the voltage at the terminals, the circuit will always see this as a voltage drop. So, at the very least, there is a sign that all is not well inside.

As for your question, **it depends** on a lot of things, perhaps most importantly on whether your protection circuit also has a temperature sensor. :) For example, if you wrapped your cell in lots of insulation and then used it at its' current limit, there's a decent chance it would overheat, regardless of its' state-of-health.

Bottom line? **A well-constructed (and designed) solution used as specified in said design should not fail, regardless of age.** Since you mentioned cheap-ish in your question, I'd keep some fire safety equipment handy. :)